# Atualizar quantidade de like/deslike com JQuery

Tags: jquery

Eu estou tentando atualizar o valor de um elemento span (aumentar ou diminuir) sempre que o botão de like é clicado.

**Importante:** O código a seguir cria outro elemento  só que com o id #unlikeBtn ao invés de #likeBtn quando o botão é clicado..

```
_create: ->
      self = this
      $(@element).css('display', 'block').css('width','100%').css('height', '36px').removeClass('like-button').addClass('like-button-widget')
      @templates =
        notLiked: '''
          <a href="{{resourceUrl}}/like" id="likeBtn" class="{{cssClass}} like-button like-icon notliked">
            </a>
        '''
        liked: '''
          <a href="{{resourceUrl}}/unlike" id="unlikeBtn" class="{{cssClass}} like-button like-icon liked">
            </a>
          '''
```

Quero atualizar o valor da contagem automaticamente toda vez que o usuário clicar no botão para curtir ou descurtir, mas a função só funciona na primeira vez. Se eu der deslike em seguida, não funciona. Somente quando eu atualizo a página e clico para descurtir o valor é atualizado.

```js
$(window).load(function() {

  $('#likeBtn').click(function() {
    $('#likesCounter').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
  });

  $('#unlikeBtn').click(function () {
    $('#likesCounter').html(function(i, val) { return val*1-1 });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="like-button-widget" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 36px;">
<a href="#" id="likeBtn" class="btcupon like-button like-icon liked">
  click</a>
</div>
<span id="likesCounter" style="font-size: 16px; color: #6e6e6e; font-weight: 600;">1</span>
```

Como faço para atualizar sempre sem ter que atualizar a página?

Comment: Executando o seu código no próprio site do Stack Overflow está funcionando.

Comment: O que acontece é que falta um pedaço de código em coffescript que cria outro elemento com o id #unlikeBtn, mas se eu clicar pela segunda vez nesse botão o valor da contagem não diminui.

Comment: Você poderia postar o código que está faltando?

Comment: Vou atualizar a pergunta.

Comment: Adicionando eventos em elementos criados dinamicamente não funciona mesmo. Já sofri bastante com isso. Adiciona o evento num elemento fixo e da foco no dinamico: assim $(body).on(''click", "#elementotal", function());

Comment: Cara não entendi a sua pergunta, ele está funcionando

Answer (score 0):

Elementos dinamicamente carregados não aceitam a adição de um `listener` diretamente. Adicione o mesmo ao elemento pai, ou em qualquer outro fixo da tela da seguinte forma:

```
 $("body").on("click", "#Seuelemento" function(){
     //Faça o que quiser
})
```